# How to initialize final field by calling method from another class?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

One class RestitController with declared service

```
@Autowired
private RestitService restitService;
```

I'd like to declare a class variable (cause it will be used by many methods  of RestitController) and fill it with the result of a method of RestitService.

Problem is that when i write something like

```
private final HashMap<K, V> map = restitService.makeMap();
```

I get `NullPointerException` because `restitService` is `null` at this moment.

Is there another way to organize my code? I'd really like avoid calling the method each time I need the map.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my rough English.

EDIT : Luigi's solution is fine. 
Just one thing : my HashMap was in reality a WeakHashMap in my code. The map was correctly loaded on the start of Tomcat but once the methods using it were called it was empty. I change the class to HashMap and the problem disappeared. Guess that Garbage Collector was behind this untimely cleaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use constructor injection

```
private RestitService restitService;
private final HashMap<K, V> map;

@Autowired
public RestitController(RestitService restitService) {
    this.restitService = restitService;
    this.map = restitService.makeMap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @PostConstruct method to do it as well.

```
@Autowired
private RestitService restitService;
private final HashMap<K, V> map=new HashMap<K, String>();

@PostConstruct
    public void initIt() throws Exception {
      this.map.putAll(restitService.makeMap());
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to assign final **`String`** but it says `the final field can not be assigned.`